# cbind with row names to several files

Tags: r, merge, split, cbind

I would like to use the `cbind` in a list of files. However each file are splited in a specific chromosome (chr) `(k in 1:29)`, and specific sample `(i in 1:777)`. The files are like:

sample1chr1.txt, sample1chr2.txt ... sample1chr29.txt, sample2chr1.txt ... sample777chr29.txt

All files have exactly the same rows names (3 first columns represent my row names). I would like to get a final file to each chr merging to all sample files, with and do not repeat the row names in the final file (the first 3 columns representing my rows names).

I tried this:

```
#Creating file with row names (3 first columns) to each Chr 
{
{for(k in 1:29){
  infile <- paste0("sample1chr",k,".txt")
  outfile <- paste0("LRRrawallchr",k,".txt")
  rows <- read.table(infile, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  rows <- rows[, -grep("Log.R.Ratio", colnames(rows))]
  write.table(rows, outfile, sep=";")}}

#Cbind in one file per Chr
{  for(i in 1:777)
  for(k in 1:29){
    base <- paste0("LRRrawallchr",k,".txt")
    chr <- read.table(base, header=TRUE, sep=";")
    infile <- paste0("sample",i,"chr",k,".txt")
    chr2 <- read.table(infile, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    outfile <- paste0("LRRrawallchr",k,".txt")
    chr2 <- chr2[, -grep("Name", colnames(chr2))]
    chr2 <- chr2[, -grep("Chr", colnames(chr2))]
    chr2 <- chr2[, -grep("Position", colnames(chr2))]
    chr <- cbind(chr, chr2)
    write.table(chr, outfile, sep=";", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)}
}
```

Input example (sample1chr1.txt):

```
 Name      Chr  Position    sample1value
BAC-11034   1   128            0.302
BAC-11044   1   129            -0.56
BAC-11057   1   134            0.0840
```

Input example (sample2chr1.txt):

```
Name       Chr  Position      sample2value
BAC-11034   1   128            0.25
BAC-11044   1   129            0.41
BAC-11057   1   134           -0.14
```

Expected output (LRRrawallchr1):

```
Name       Chr  Position    sample1value   sample2value
BAC-11034   1   128         0.302          0.25
BAC-11044   1   129         -0.56          0.41
BAC-11057   1   134         0.0840         -0.14
```

I have 22553 different .txt files (29 files (one per chr) to each of 777 samples). All 22553 files (sample1chr1.txt, sample1chr2.txt ... sample1chr29.txt, sample2chr1.txt ... sample777chr29.txt) are like above example.

I wanna 29 files like (LRRrawallchr1), one per Chr. The "LRRrawallchr,k," files have to be with 777+3 (800 collumns). The 3 row names and one column per sample.

Cheers!

Comment: Please make this a reproducible example by including example data which shows the problem.  Include the data in the question itself.

Comment: That is enough? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a <- NULL
for(k in 1:29)
{
a <- read.table(paste0("sample1chr", k, ".txt"), header=TRUE, sep="\t")
for(i in 2:777)
{
infile <- read.table(paste0("sample", i, "chr", k, ".txt"), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

a <- merge(a, infile, by = c('Name', 'Chr', 'Position'))
}
write.table(a, paste0("LRRrawallchr", k, ".csv"), append = FALSE, sep = ",", row.names = F)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `merge` the sets, not `cbind` them.  `merge` will combine rows based on common or specified column names.  After reading the first two into data frames, this command produces the merge.  I am giving the common column names to merge (with `by`) as you are filtering by these names in your code.

```
> merge(sample1chr1, sample1chr2, by=c('Name', 'Chr', 'Position'))
       Name Chr Position sample1value sample2value
1 BAC-11034   1      128        0.302         0.25
2 BAC-11044   1      129       -0.560         0.41
3 BAC-11057   1      134        0.084        -0.14
```

Then continue to merge in following sets.

Comment: I can´t merge. All data is too big. I am trying some way to bind one sample per time. Some way to cbind the sample1 , and write, cbind sample2 and write, cbind sample3 and write.... 
Reaching in the end all samples to each Chr separately...

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the rows is always identical for all files and only the last column's value change, then you can `cbind()` only the last column of each file, where (starting from k=2):

```
infile <- cbind(infile, chr[, 4])
```

Where `infile` is the file where your data collect, and `chr` is your newly-loaded file inside the loop. If your rows are not ranked in the same order, see @Matthew's solution.

PS: This will result in a file with more than 22 thousand columns. That's not a good format for most procedures in R

Comment: My problem is that my final result have just one "sample,i,value". I am wondering if it is possible to write my output and read again 777 times (one to each sample). Resulting in a file with all collumns (3+ 777) in the end. Your procedure just salve me the `grep` steps. I am wrong?

Comment: No you are right, that's why I put the PS at the end. Then I suggest you first put them in a long dataset (using `rbind`) and then look into `dcast()` from the package `reshape2`.